# Composer как правильно подключить массив настроек

Tags: php, composer

Как **правильно** подключить через composer файл массив с настройками.
И далее в нужном месте использовать `include "array_config.php";`

array_config.php будет содержать

```
return ['abc'=>$this->lalalala,'asd'=>$abcs];
```

composer.json

```
{
...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"ParserBase": "src/"},
    "files": ["src/functions_include.php"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Composer не должен заниматься такой функцией. Похоже, что вы плохо представляете себе назначение composer-а.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman тем не менее в композере можно объявить файлы подгружаемые до запуска приложения.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае композер в чистом виде вам не помощник, может быть вам стоит обратить внимание на плагины для него https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md